# NSUTF8StringEncoding issue in IOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding. My app is running in IOS 6 as well as IOS 7 and no issue with that but the problem is with IOS 7.

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@app1.php?loc=%@", URL, [param stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

1. in IOS6 it's encoded like :
 http://mydomain/app1.php?loc=Select%20Office%20location

2. in IOS7 it's encoded like :
 http://mydomain/app1.php?loc=Select%C2%A0Office%C2%A0location
```

Now the problem is php server accept the no. 1 encoding I mean which is encoded by IOS6. So when my app is running in IOS7 php server return zero result while it returning in IOS6 can any one help me to get out of this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact value of param?

Comment: param contain "Select Office location"

Comment: Put a `NSLog(@"%@", param);` and paste the results both in iOS6 and iOS7. After a simple test of `[@"Select Office location" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` iOS7 returns the correct result, so your `param` has some other problem.

Comment: How it could be possible?? Same app same param value only the system version is changed. Currently I am sitting with two iPhone with IOS6 and IOS7. In both iPhone I have installed the new ipa with an alert and I found.

Comment: @graver, If you still believe that the issue with param. It's in [app store](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/sarasota-memorial/id397478168?mt=8). Download it and run it in IOS6 & IOS7 then hope you could found what I am tried to say. For IOS6 it's return data but For IOS7 it's return nil

Comment: Well, I am not saying that there's no issue, but looking where could it be, because my simple test encodes correctly under ios7 so the problem could be somewhere else.

Comment: Ok one thing. Are you building it in xcode5? I guess so. My app is build in xcode4 and building target is 6.1.

Comment: Just tested on Xcode 4.6.3 sdk 6.1, run on iOS 7. Encodes correctly again. Is it possible the param to come from the server and be decoded incorrectly in the first place or something like that ?

Comment: I've been through IOS5- IOS6 then now IOS6 to IOS7, there are always changes that seems to screw up a perfectly running apps.  You should read this documentation from apple https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes

Comment: It basically says that they cannot be responsible for incorrect escape character sequence interpretation and recommends a pre-processing the string to take out invalid characters. So what you can do is convert the string to UTF8 first from UTF16 (which is the native coding of IOS) before running the stringbyaddingpercentescape ...

Comment: Guys still I am confused.. What I have do exactly. Please be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL encoded "%C2%A0" string is an Unicode "Non-breaking space" in UTF-8 encoding.

See wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

IMHO, there is nothing against the occurrence of an Unicode "Non-breaking space" in an unencoded parameter string in the URL query.

In order to check whether there is a difference in the original unencoded parameter string in iOS 6 respectively iOS 7, you need to look at the bytes, for example, creating a `NSData` object from the param string with UTF-8 encoding and log this `NSData` object to the console.

Printing a `NSString` object may have the same appearance in a text editor or the console.